# Sphinx search with CJK (Japanese)

Tags: sphinx

I'll try to index by Sphinx some JAPANESE CONTENT in my project but it returns

**ERROR: index 'idx_jp_main': sql_fetch_row: Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x83\x94\xE3\x83\xBC...' for column 'title' at row 1.**

Somebody can help me, I've used utf8, utf8mb4, cp932, sjis and ujis but nothing, I have used also CJK Language to charset-table and ngram_chars but nothing same.

Thanks!